# How to get the maximum power transfer

Tags: power, resistors

How to show that **R***load* = **R***source* maximizes the power in the load for a given resistance?

Comment: This is really clearly homework, it's answered *all over the internet*, and you don't show any own attempt. Vote to close as too broad.

Comment: Please use the title to explain the subject matter not "I need help to solve this problem". Every question on the site is "I need help to solve this problem".

Comment: Google "Mathematical proof of maximum power transfer theorem"

Answer (score 3):

I wont give you the answer but I will tell you how you can get it.

Consider the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq1ruj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- Find out the power Pd dissipated in Rload
- Find out the condition where Pd is maximized